# Filter files in directory by filename pattern for a snakemake pipeline

Tags: python, snakemake

I have a directory with files that have the following pattern: <ID>.<date>.json. Some of the IDs are duplicated with different dates. I want to filter the files with the most recent date for each ID.

**How can I implement this filtering step in snakemake?**

I already have a python function that returns a list of filtered files. This is a minimal example of the snakemake file:

```py
import os
import re

dir_path = "path/to/dir/"
out_dir = "path/to/result_dir"

def get_most_recent_files(wildcards):

  dir = dir_path
  file_pattern = re.compile(r"([A-Za-z0-9]+)\.(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}).json$")
  id_files = {}

  for filename in os.listdir(dir): 
    match = file_pattern.match(filename)
    if match: 
        id, date = match.groups()
        id_files.setdefault(id, []).append((filename, date))

  most_recent_files = {}
  for id, files in id_files.items(): 
    files.sort(key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
    most_recent_files[id] = files[0][0]
  
  return [dir + file for file in most_recent_files.values()]


rule all: 
    input: 
        out_dir + "{ID}_parsed.csv"

rule parse_jsons: 
    input: 
        get_most_recent_files
    output: 
        out_dir + "{ID}_parsed.csv"
    script: 
        "parser.py"
```

But like this I get the error:

`Wildcards in input files cannot be determined from output files: 'ID'`

So I am not sure where I should provide the wildcard "PID".

I tried different approaches with glob_wildcards and expand, but nothing really worked.

Answer (score 1):

This is my minimal example using the code you provided:

```
.
├── Snakefile
└── input
    ├── bar.2021-12-31.json
    ├── baz.2022-05-15.json
    ├── foo.2022-01-01.json
    └── foo.2023-03-19.json
```

You need to provide the ID in rule all using `expand()` :

```
dir_path = "input/"
out_dir = "output/"

dir = dir_path
file_pattern = re.compile(r"([A-Za-z0-9]+)\.(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}).json$")
id_files = {}

for filename in os.listdir(dir):
    match = file_pattern.match(filename)
    if match:
      id, date = match.groups()
      id_files.setdefault(id, []).append((filename, date))

most_recent_files = {}
for id, files in id_files.items():
    files.sort(key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
    most_recent_files[id] = files[0][0]

def json_extract(id):
    return most_recent_files[id]

rule all:
    input:
        expand(out_dir + "{id}.txt", id = most_recent_files.keys())

rule parse_jsons:
    input:
        lambda wildcards: dir + json_extract(wildcards.id)
    output:
        out_dir + "{id}.txt"
    shell:
        """
        echo {input} > {output}
        """
```

Here is the same example using glob_wildcards:

```
(ID, DATE,) = glob_wildcards(dir_path + "{id}.{date}.json")

most_recent_files = {}
for id in set(ID):
    dates, = glob_wildcards(dir_path + id + ".{date}.json")
    maxdate = max(dates)
    most_recent_files[id] = maxdate

def latest_date(id):
    return most_recent_files[id]

rule all:
    input:
        expand(out_dir + "{id}.txt", id = most_recent_files.keys())

rule parse_jsons:
    input:
        lambda wildcards: expand(dir_path + "{id}.{date}.json", id = {wildcards.id}, date = latest_date(wildcards.id))
    output:
        out_dir + "{id}.txt"
    shell:
        """
        echo {input} > {output}
        """
```